# Symfony: Images still save in web/uploads after I changed web root to public_html

Tags: file-upload, symfony1, root

In my symfony project, I changed my webroot directory to public_html to fit with a specific host.

However, in the admin generator, when saving a file, the system creates a web folder, then stores the image in web/uploads

**How can I tell the system to now save in public_html instead?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony v 1.0

The uploads are saved based on variables stored in the constants.php file.

```
symfony data folder / symfony / config / constants.php
```

In this case, the 2 required were:

```
  'sf_web_dir_name'     => $sf_web_dir_name     = 'web',
  'sf_upload_dir_name'  => $sf_upload_dir_name  = 'uploads',
```